# return a generic reference from unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, reference, value-type, unmanaged-memory

I have a generic class

```
class UnmanagedArray<T> where T: struct 
{
    IntPtr _backing; // unmanaged memory

    // some constructors and others methods

    // very slow but I don't care
    public T this[int index] 
    {
        get 
        {
            int elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(default(T));       
            byte* ptr = ((byte*)tab) + index * elementSize;         
            T result = default(T);      
            var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(result, GCHandleType.Pinned);       
            byte* result_ptr = (byte*) handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();           
            for(int k = 0; k < elementSize; ++k)        
            {
                result_ptr[k] = ptr[k];         
            }
            handle.Free();      
            return result;
        } 
    }
```

}

Now I'd like to modify elements in my array. 
Something like

```
myArray[i].prop = 12;
```

I can't do it because

> cannot modify the return value of Array.this[int] because it is
>   not a variable.

I totally understand the error, since `T` is a ValueType, therefore immutable (returned by copy).

Is there any way to make a `ref return` in my indexer property?

PS : `T` cannot be a reference type. It has to be a ValueType.

Comment: Even if you could, you're be returning `result`, not something related to the memory identified by `_backing`. I hope you've already stopped and seriously asked yourself if you've picked the right tool (language) for the job here?

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE variant of your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?